# Rails: Modify URL in view and refresh with that new value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, page-refresh

I am dealing with URLs of this style:

```
http://mysite/tables/134/X/Y
http://mysite/tables/134/X/Z
```

The number 134 is recognized as **:table_id** in the related controllers.  I would like to be able to (from the view), change the **:table_id** and call the same URL.  So, something like:

```
http://mysite/tables/135/X/Y
```

I have tried doing it like this:

```
<%= collection_select("params", :table_id, @tables , :id, :id, {:prompt => true}, :onchange => "location.href = ''") %>
```

But the params[:table_id] that I get in the controller it keeps being the old one that I had in the URL.  So my question is:

**Do I need to build the URL by myself? Can't I just change params[:table_id] and reload the same URL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you need to build the URL.

Reason: The variable `params[:table_id]` comes from the URL. I'm sure you've seen website urls of the form `http://www.foo.com/?var=baz`. If you do this in Rails, it will set params[:var] to be baz. That's basically what happens here with table_id.

A basic principle of REST is that the HTTP transactions are stateless. (Cookies and session storage are an exception, but that's not relevant here.)